# Best approach for Forms solutions on SP 2013 on-prem, Sp 2016 and SP Online

Tags: workflow, infopath

I've been tasked with preparing an update for the team on the best solutions for forms on SharePoint, both 2013 on-prem, SP online and SP 2016.

I know InfoPath will be *supported* until 2022, but that's not the same as saying this is the MS recommended solution. And since we need a responsive design, it's not even an option.

Given that there is no official word from MS, what approaches are people using and what are your experiences like with these?

Using a custom solution, leveraging something like Angular JS seems cool, but would require dev input to modify forms. (Maybe that's a good thing! :D )

The third-parties (Ninex, K2, etc) seem cool, but there are licensing and vendor lock-in concerns.

Does anyone have any real-world experiences? One obvious big concern we have is migration if MS do ever announce an OOTB alternative. And management like the idea of storing data in SP lists. ("Easier to leverage existing skill-sets" - i.e. non-devs can go in there and mess things up. :D)

Thanks!
Jane

Comment: Closing this as the only  people who would know are the product team at this point, and anything else would be speculative.

Comment: So in other words, there is no publicly available MS recommended best practice?

Comment: There were actually two parts to my question, sorry for not making it plainer.

Comment: Is there a roadmap? (If not then I agree, speculation, but a simple no would suffice.) The second part, which Isn't as clear as it should have been, is what then, based upon expert experience, is the best approach? Custom code or third-party?

Comment: If you can edit the question so it can be answered more definitively, then it can be reopened.

Comment: How's that? :D Thanks for the tip! I'm new on here.

Answer (score 0):

I specifically asked about this at Ignite this year as there was nothing that talked about the future in this space. Kashman dodged the question stating the group was going to make an announcement when ready.

The stance I've seen most is to still use InfoPath. We are using it in our ventures into SPO. There are other alternatives like the model binding javascript frameworks, third parties, and client side rendering. They all have their pros and cons.

I wish I had more information on it so I knew how to proceed myself. I don't want to invest in areas that are uncertain but also don't want to invest in dying areas. But that being said, sometimes the devil you know is better than the devil you don't, so we're sticking with InfoPath until something definitive is released.

Comment: Yeah, I know a company who are doing that becuase they have basically 12 guys trained on InfoPath and they're highly productive. The concern is that with each project they complete, the future migration hole potentially gets deeper. We have no InfoPath skills, so I'm thinking a sensible future-proof friend approach might be to store all data in SP lists, use one of the JS frameworks to render, data validate, etc, and avoid complex workflows as much as possible.

Comment: the beauty with infopath is that it can be a document (stored as an xml file) or tied to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I've pushed my clients away from InfoPath, and use SharePoint Designer Forms. You can do custom development, leverage Bootstrap, AngularJS, Breeze, jQuery and any other tools that help you bridge the gap between idea and solution. If you are doing more queries with REST/CSOM it will be supported in the next versions and in SP Online.

This also gives a very small, selected, few power users the ability to change some things here and there, as long as the form/code is written in such a way to get them to edit carefully.

I've completed many projects using SharePoint Designer, and with the way that InfoPath behaves sometimes, I wouldn't want to go back.

Comment: Thanks Mike! The concern we have with SPD is the difficulty to do any meaningful ALM, managed deployment or Unit Testing. (InfoPath was even worse!)